# angularjs - input number localization does not work

Tags: angularjs

i'm trying to use a , instead of the . in the number input field. i added the correct angular-locale_de-at.js. but on the validation with `formname.fieldname.$valid` and `formname.fieldname.$error` i always get the message, that the value e.g. 9,9 is not valid. but if i enter 9.9 it works. if i look at the $locale, the ID is de-at. and the js file is also included in the index.html ... what's wrong here? is there something else i have to include?

best regards.

Comment: please post Fiddle or Plunker to help us to detect the issue. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately Angular does not handle localized inputs out of the box. Moreover there is no *parser* implementation based on the locale, only formatter. So you will have to implement (1) a parser that takes the locale into account and (2) a directive that cooperates with `ngModel`, includes your parser in `ngModel.$parsers` and Angular's filter in the `ngModel.$formatters`.